When running a customtkinter script in pycharm 3.12 window does not show up
I was trying to run a simple GUI script I learned (I am a beginner) and no window popped up with the GUI
this was the code,
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode('dark')
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme('dark-blue')

root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry('500x300')

def login():
    print('Test')


    frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=root)
    frame.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill='both', expand=True)

    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame, text='Login System', text_font=('Roboto', 24))
    label.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

    entry1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame, placeholder_text='Username')
    entry1.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

    entry2 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame, placeholder_text='Password', show='*')
    entry2.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

    button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame, text="Login", command=login)
    button.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

    checkbox = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(master=frame, text='Remember Me')
    checkbox(pady=12, padx=10)

I tried adding,
root.mainloop()

to the end of the script but it still didn't work. Can anyone help me?

Adding root.mainloop() should show an empty window.

I've tried that but it just immediately ends and returns a code 0

@NathanHaug First you need to fix the indentation of your code.  Second as other comment, there are issues in your code, like checkbox(pady=12, padx=10) should be checkbox.pack(pady=12, padx=10) instead.

The issue in your script is that the function login() contains the code for creating the GUI elements, but you are not calling this function. Since login() is supposed to be the callback for the button, it only gets triggered when the button is pressed.
There's also a small mistake with the checkbox. You are calling the checkbox like a function (checkbox(pady=12, padx=10)), but it should be checkbox.pack(pady=12, padx=10) like the other widgets.
Finally, the text_font argument should be called font instead.
Here's the script:
import customtkinter 

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode('dark')
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme('dark-blue')

root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry('500x300')

def login():
    print('Test')

frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=root)
frame.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill='both', expand=True)

label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame, text='Login System', font=('Roboto', 24))
label.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

entry1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame, placeholder_text='Username')
entry1.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

entry2 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame, placeholder_text='Password', show='*')
entry2.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame, text="Login", command=login)
button.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

checkbox = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(master=frame, text='Remember Me')
checkbox.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

root.mainloop()


